# Having trouble using class as a key within Scala map. Any help appreciated

Tags: scala, types, hashmap, maps, key

Beginner here and I've been having some difficulty getting one of my maps to work within Scala.  My nested map `symmetryTable` contains keys of the type `Shape` which is class that I have implemented.  Whenever I test this in a Scala worksheet using concrete examples i.e. `Shapes_sample.symmetryTable(Shapes_sample.corner)("ne")` the lookup works perfectly.  However, when I try to implement this into an actual function i.e. `this.shapes.symmetryTable(shape)(direction)` I always get the error "key is not found" regarding the `shape` key.  I have checked the type and data of the `shape` key variable being passed in and it is of the correct type and it also contains a class that should be in `SymmetryTable`.  I don't know why it keeps  telling me that it is not found.  I also had to deal with some difficulties with generic data types, but those appear to have been fixed as I can the `shape` key seems to be of the correct.  There is a lot of background code to this so I may not be able to provide a minimum working sample but I will give as much code as I can.  This is a first time passion project of mine and I really want to get it working!

Here's my function where I verify the data of the `shape` key.  It passes this test every time.  Provided that it contains valid key (which I'm very sure it does), I don't know why it is not working properly and why it can't look up.  Will I have to tweak the HashMap equality functions or something?  I'm not sure and I don't know how to tackle it.  Any help is greatly appreciated

```
  def getSymmetriesForShape(shape: Any, direction: String): Set[Shape] =
    shape match {
      case shape: Shape =>
        this.shapes.symmetryTable(shape)(direction)
      case _ =>
        Set.empty[Shape]
    }
```

Comment: What's the type of `symmetryTable` and what data are you using as an example that doesn't work ?

Comment: Could you share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? With only that piece of code is not enough to understand the problem. Also share the error message and the stacktrace if it is possible

Comment: Also keep in mind that using `Any` is strongly discouraged if you want to write "safe" code and I believe here is a perfect example of an issue you wouldn't have with proper types.

Comment: Show definitions of `Shape`, `shapes`, `corner` and `symmetryTable`. And yeah ... why `Any`???

Comment: I would bet the problem is that `Shape` is a regular `class` rather than a `case class`, as such its `hashCode` and `equals` will be reference-based rather than value-based.

Comment: @luisMiguelMejiaSuarez I think this might be it.  `Shape` is actually defined as a case class.  But there is also a single regular instance of `Shape` inside a larger class.  What I'm trying to do is compare these two and I can't get it to work.  I can upload some of my class and data types soon (at work at the moment) and that might help.  In the meantime, is there another way that you can compare a case and a regular.  I was thinking about just making my own custom compare function and going from there, but it would be nice to know if there is a better way for future projects